# wrap only text within a selection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup repeating several times on a page:

```
<div class="RebalanceCellBroadACName">
   <img src="someimage.png" />
   Accounts
</div>
```

Where I wish to use jquery to wrap only the word "accounts" in a span with the class .orange-category.
I have found that the following:

```
$(".RebalanceCellBroadACName").wrapInner("<span class='orange-category' />");
```

wraps both the image and the text. 
This when typed in the console returns all of the instances of the text concatenated together:

```
$(".RebalanceCellBroadACName").text();
```

However the following returns an error "undefined is not a function", and I assume this is because I am selecting a string rather than a jQuery object.

```
$(".RebalanceCellBroadACName").text().wrapAll("<span class='orange-category' />");
```

So any help would be appreciated as to how to best achieve the folowing result via jquery:

```
<div class="RebalanceCellBroadACName">
   <img src="someimage.png" />
   <span class='orange-category' />Accounts</span>
</div>
```

For every instance of .RebalanceCellBroadACName on the page. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Not a solution but you're not closing the `src` attribute of your img ( " is missing)

Answer (score 2):

A solution :

```
$(".RebalanceCellBroadACName").each(function(){
    var img = $('img', this).detach();
    $(this).wrapInner("<span class='orange-category' />").prepend(img);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While you don't have access to the text node, you do have access to the children that are DOM elements.

So basically you can clone the parent, remove the children, wrap the text and finally replace it in the original.

```
$(".RebalanceCellBroadACName").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    var all_text = $this.html();
    var clean_text = $this.clone()    //clone the element
                       .children() //select all the children
                       .remove()   //remove all the children
                       .end()  //again go back to selected element
                       .text().trim();
    var new_text = "<span class='orange-category'>"+clean_text+"</span>"    

    $this.html(all_text.replace(clean_text, new_text));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2he9h2k/